# 100 Door problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> 100 people, numbered 1 to 100, are standing in a long hallway that has 100 closed doors also numbered 1 to 100. Person 1 walks down the hallway, opening every door. Person 2 walks down the hallway and closes every door that is a multiple of 2. Person 3 walks down the hallway and changes every door that is a multiple of 3. (That is, if the door is open, they close it, and if it is closed, they open it.) Person 4 changes every door that is a multiple of 4, Person 5 every door that is a multiple of 5, etc. This continues until all 100 people have walked down the hallway and changed their doors. How many times will Door 12 be changed?

I came across this question and didn't manage to find a simple solution for it. So following my intuition I prime factorized $12= 2^2 \cdot 3$ and then calculated the number of divisors $d=3 \cdot2 = 6$ and turns out that was the correct answer. Was this just pure coincidence or what would be the explanation for this?

Comment: Door $12$ is changed by exaclty those persons having a number dividing $12$, so your solution is utterly valid and logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call opening/closing an operation.

On door $n$ there obiously are $\tau(n)$ operations

Door 12 will be changed 6 times

Moreover, if we, for example want to see how many doors are open in the end, we observe that if and inly if we do an odd number of operations on a doorm it is open in the end, so because $\tau(n)$ is only odd when $n$ is a perfect square, only doors $1,4,9...100$ Will be opened.

Your intuition is correct and it is not coincidence.